# Como usar grant reference

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle

Tengo 2 esquemas en *oracle*, cada uno con su usuario y contraseña. Tengo uno de facturación y otro de nómina, de los cuales en el esquema de facturación tengo una tabla llamada `fct_personas` y en nómina tengo una tabla llamada `nomi_empleados`.

Quisiera saber como usar el `grant reference` para permisos al momento de insertar valores en las tablas; por ejemplo, si tengo 10 registros en la tabla `fct_personas`, en el esquema `nomi_empleados`, no debería dejarme insertar un empleado con `id` numero `11` mientras este `id` (`11`) no exista en la tabla `fct_personas`, esto intente pero me da error:

```
grant references on usr_facturacion.fct_personas to usr_nomina.nomi_empleados
```

Comment: Te puse una respuesta, pero para referencia futura, para esto tipo de preguntas, obviamente es útil especificar el error preciso que recibistes.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error? Es recomendable copiar y pegar lo que te sale (ojalá como texto)

Answer (score 2):

Conectado con el usuario `usr_facturacion`, puedes ejecutar la sentencia siguiente:

```
grant references on fct_personas to usr_nomina
```

Como puedes ver, el permiso se lo das a un usuario, no a una tabla.

Una vez que este grant te funcione, ahora puedes conectarte con el usuario `usr_nomina` y definir un foreign key constraint que haga referencia a la tabla `usr_facturacion.fct_personas`. No conozco los nombres de tus columnas, pero sería algo así:

```
alter table nomi_empleados
add constraint nomi_empleados_fk01
foreign key (id)
references usr_facturacion.fct_personas(id)
```